# Avoid redundant code in python/scrapy

Tags: python, scrapy, response, extract

I am VERY new to python and scrapy. I wrote a working script with the use of scrapy and need a little improvement to avoid redundancies.

At the parse_article_page function I came across 2 possibilities. Either the article has variants (more pages to scrap) or not. Can you help me to avoid the double use of the code in the else-statement and parse_data function?

I tried a second request, but this seems not to work. Log says "DEBUG: Filtered duplicate request" or it says nothing.

```
def parse_article_page(self, response):
    #Check for variants
    variants = response.xpath('//div[@class="variants"]/select/option[not(@disabled)]/@variant_href').extract()
    if len(variants) > 1:
        for variant in variants:
            variant_url = response.urljoin(variant) 
            #Request article variants:
            yield scrapy.Request(variant_url, callback=self.parse_data) 
    else:
        #yield scrapy.Request(response.url, callback=self.parse_data) #Does not work
        item = ShopItem()
        item['desc'] = response.css(description_selector).extract()
        item['price'] = response.css(price_selector).extract()
        item['itno'] = response.css(no_selector).extract()
        item['url'] = response.url
        yield item

def parse_data(self, response):
    item = ShopItem()
    item['desc'] = response.css(description_selector).extract()
    item['price'] = response.css(price_selector).extract()
    item['itno'] = response.css(no_selector).extract()
    item['url'] = response.url
    yield item
```

Comment: Why can't you simply call `parse_data` from the `else` clause of `parse_article_page`?

Comment: I don't know how this could be helpful as i have limited python knowledge  , think of recursive functions.

Comment: I am new in the language and only followed a tutorial and end up with the code above. I spend already hours to find an answer with google. How do I do a simply call with the response?

Comment: better find tutorial for Python. `else: self.parse_data(response)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

calling `else: self.parse_data(response)` won't work because you still need to yield the item inside that method for scrapy to get it, You'll have to do something like this:

```
def parse_article_page(self, response):
    #Check for variants
    variants = response.xpath('//div[@class="variants"]/select/option[not(@disabled)]/@variant_href').extract()
    if len(variants) > 1:
        for variant in variants:
            variant_url = response.urljoin(variant) 
            #Request article variants:
            yield scrapy.Request(variant_url, callback=self.parse_data) 
    else:
        for item in self.parse_data(response):
            yield item

def parse_data(self, response):
    item = ShopItem()
    item['desc'] = response.css(description_selector).extract()
    item['price'] = response.css(price_selector).extract()
    item['itno'] = response.css(no_selector).extract()
    item['url'] = response.url
    yield item
```